# How can I resolve this: Failed to build module 'FrameworkA' for importation due to the errors above

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, swift-package-manager

The problem itself is simple to describe. I have two projects to create frameworks FrameworkA and FrameworkB. Framework B depends on Framework A. Both of which have a target with a run script([Run_Script](https://gist.github.com/quangDecember/6151c0af180a84b79f8b572e289b668f)) to spit out a xcframework in their respective project root directory. I add the product FrameworkA.xcframework as a dependency to FrameworkB. As expected, I can import and use FrameworkA and build Framework B and it's xcframework generating target. So far so good.

Now I add a Swift package (doesn't matter what package) to Framework A, try and build Framework B. I cannot build FrameworkB. due to error below:

`Failed to build module 'FrameworkA' for importation due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug`

[image: Failed to build module for importation]

and
in `arm64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface`
[image: arm64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface]

Is this a compiler bug as XCode warns?
I have created a sample project to illustrate this issue. [TestXCF](https://github.com/aswathr/TestXCF)

The first commit compiles and the last fails. Using XCode 13.3, default toolchain

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I did not. But if you only need the implementation of SamplePackage you could add the qualifier `@_implementationOnly` in places where you import SamplePackage. https://forums.swift.org/t/update-on-implementation-only-imports/26996

Comment: @Aswath Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @GAURAVVIG see my comment above.